# Verify Open SSL SHA1 hash in Java

Tags: java, openssl, hmacsha1

In our project we create a SHA1 hash using following OpenSSL functions,

```
SHA_CTX ctx;
SHA1_Init (&ctx);
SHA1_Update (&ctx, value, size);
SHA1_Final (returned_hash, &ctx);
```

We are using a key and SHA1_Update is called multiple times.

I have to verify that hash using Java. I have written following functions,

```
public static Mac hmacSha1Init(String key) {
        Mac mac = null;
        try {
            // Get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
            byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

            // Get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
            mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            mac.init(signingKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return mac;
    }

    public static Mac hmacSha1Update(String value, Mac mac) {
        try {
            // update hmac with value
            mac.update(value.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return mac;
    }

    public static String hmacSha1Final( Mac mac) {
        try {
            // Compute the hmac on input data bytes
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal();
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(rawHmac);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I am using the hmacSha1Init with the key and update multiple times with the Mac and finally call hmacSha1Final with the mac.

Ex.

```
Mac mac =  hmacSha1Init("ssdsdsdioj298932276302392pdsdsfsdfs");


mac = hmacSha1Update("value1", mac);
mac = hmacSha1Update("value2", mac);
mac = hmacSha1Update("value3"', mac);
String hash =  hmacSha1Final(mac);
```

But I do not get same SHA1 hash generated via OpenSSL. There is very limited documentation on the web. Can someone please direct me

Comment: First problem - don't use the parameterless `getBytes()` method. It's probably not the issue in this particular case, but it's a really bad idea to use the system default encoding, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks Jon, I changed my code (not in the qn) but as you suspected it wasn't the case. But thanks

Comment: Could you give the details of your actual output and the expected output? I have a *guess*, but it could be wrong...

Comment: Also note that in your OpenSSL code you appear to just be using SHA-1, not HMAC-SHA-1. You're not providing any key data, for example. Are you sure you shouldn't just be using SHA-1 in the Java code?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not familiar with the OpenSSL implementation. I only got the above from the person who is doing that part. He is using a key and said that is the first part to be hashed. The expected result (in hex) is d01abdc697573b325ffe9b17dcf29e85582860bb where I am getting 7683473346af618e10e824ebc16224ac76425738

Comment: @JonSkeet when i use direct java using MessageDigest I get the output as da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Comment: Well you are correct @JonSkeet when I append all the values into a one big string and do a SHA1 it works. :(

Comment: You shouldn't need to put it all into a big string. But you do need to understand whether you're trying to use SHA-1 or HMAC-SHA-1.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the two hashes to be different is that the input used in the openssl SHA1 algorithm is different that the one is used in Java framework. 
If you use the MD5 algorithm you will see that the result is the same. In this case openssl uses the same.

What changes? Well, openssl considered SHA1 not safe enough, fine, so they decided to give it another turn. Normally (MD5 and Java framework), take the input string and generate an ASN1 DER encoding of it. Then they take it and pass it to the algorithm. For SHA1 openssl is doing a normalization before generating the ASN1 DER encoding. It is calculating the CANONICAL format of the input, then generating the ASN1 DER and then passing it to the algorithm.

You will have to modify the Java framework to get the same results. I am trying to do it myself too :)

Here you can find a post about it in the openssl distribution list: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/The-new-subject-hash-algorithm-td44844.html

And here an implementation from the ICM Uniwersytet Warszawski. Not sure how reliable it is, that's why I am trying myself.

https://github.com/eu-emi/canl-java/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/emi/security/authn/x509/helpers/trust/OpensslTruststoreHelper.java